# How to use iterators in recursive calls mutating a sequence of data?

Tags: recursion, rust, borrow-checker

#### TL/DR

I have a recursive algorithm where every call wants to modify entries in an iterable data structure (a `Vec`). How do I properly model this in Rust using iterators?

#### Disclaimer

The problem arose in a different, more complex context and I tried to build a rather minimal example which highlights the issue. I am mentioning this to explain that it won't help me if you recommend an entirely different solution to the particular problem I am solving in the below code, which is subset sum.

#### Example

Consider the following code, and remove a single slash in front of either option to comment it out. Now, option 1 compiles and works as expected, but option 2 does not compile.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Item {
    in_subset: bool,
    value: u32,
}

fn try_find_subset_with_sum(items: &mut Vec<Item>, goal: u32) -> bool {
    let current = items
        .iter()
        .filter(|x| x.in_subset)
        .fold(0, |sum, x| sum + x.value);
    if current == goal {
        true
    } else {
        if current > goal {
            false
        } else {
            //* OPTION 1: ********************************
            for k in 0..items.len() {
                if !items[k].in_subset {
                    items[k].in_subset = true;
                    if try_find_subset_with_sum(items, goal) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    items[k].in_subset = false;
                }
            }
            // *******************************************/
            //* OPTION 2: ********************************
            for x in items.iter_mut() {
                if !x.in_subset {
                    x.in_subset = true;
                    if try_find_subset_with_sum(items, goal) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        x.in_subset = false
                    }
                }
            }
            // *******************************************/
            false
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tmp = vec![12, 9, 2, 1, 13, 46, 5, 5, 9];
    let mut set: Vec<Item> = tmp
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| Item {
            in_subset: false,
            value: x,
        })
        .collect();
    if try_find_subset_with_sum(&mut set, 16) {
        println!("found the following subset:");
        for x in set {
            if x.in_subset {
                println!("{}", x.value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error message for option 2 states:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*items` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:33:49
   |
30 |             for x in items.iter_mut() {
   |                      ----------------
   |                      |
   |                      first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                      first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
...
33 |                     if try_find_subset_with_sum(items, goal) {
   |                                                 ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I understand what the compiler is telling me. If it were human, I would yell back at it to *"just borrow the darn iterable whenever I modify the data and get it back before the recursive call for crying out loud!"* -- but I do understand that it probably can't do that.

#### The Question

Is there a more elegant way to solve this than option 1? Is there any way to do this with iterators?

Comment: Short answer: no :)

Comment: You could use interior mutability, https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3286942e9da4c9914d66ffb84406fef2, but I don't like that.

Comment: In this simple example, one strategy to address the issue would be to build a separate output structure so that the input doesn’t need to be mutated: `fn try_find_subset_with_sum(values: &[u32], goal: u32) -> Option<Vec<bool>>`. Would that strategy apply in your more complex context?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I would have to think about that for a bit, it is quite possible, I see where you're going with it. @Stargateur I don't hate  those `Cell` types in fact ... why don't you like them? Thanks everyone for the helpful comments! I feel my question is answered, and I will pretty much accept any answer that summarizes these comments ;)